# Vectorizar este código

Tags: r, bucles

Tengo el siguiente código de R donde "eventos" y "tratamentos" son data.frames diferentes pero con una columna en común (ID). Me gustaría saber si a alguién se le ocurre la forma de llevar a cabo las ejecuciones de este código pero sin usar bucles, dado que trabajo con millones de datos y R no es capaz de procesarlo así.

```
for (i in 1:unique(tratamentos$ID)){

     tratamentos$IC_data[tratamentos$ID==i]=as.numeric(tapply(eventos$FECHA, 
     eventos$evento=="insuf.cardiaca" & eventos$ID==tratamentos$ID[i], 
     min[2])


}
```

Explico en detalle lo que hace el código:
El objeto "tratamentos" contiene filas que representan a un paciente que ha recibido un tratamiento concreto. Pueden existir varias filas por paciente si reciben varios tratamientos. Cada una de estas filas tiene en sus columnas el número de identificación del paciente, la fecha en la que se receta el tratamiento y la duración del mismo.
Por otro lado, el objeto "eventos" contiene una serie de sucesos que pueden ocurrir a los pacientes. Concretamente, cada fila tiene el número de identificación del paciente, el suceso que padece y la fecha del mismo. Nuevamente, puede haber varias filas por paciente (por ejemplo, un paciente puede ser diagnosticado con insuficiencia cardiaca y, paralelamente a eso, en otro momento ser diagnosticado con una arritmia).
Debo realizar un estudio que relaciona la ingesta de ciertos tratamientos con la frecuencia de estos sucesos. Para ello estoy reuniendo en un único documento toda la información. Concretamente, quiero incluir en cada fila de "tratamentos" el/los evento/s del paciente asociado a cada fila con su/s fecha/s.
tratamentos$ID representa los IDs (muchos repetidos) de todos los pacientes que recibieron algún tratamiento. tratamentos$IC_data contiene las fechas de todos los diagnóticos de insuficiencia cardiaca de cada paciente. eventos$FECHA recoge la fecha del evento de la fila en cuestión. eventos$evento recoge el tipo de evento conreto de la fila en cuestión. eventos$ID representa los IDs (muchos repetidos) de todos los pacientes que sufrieron algún evento.
Mi código intenta sustraer del objeto "eventos", de todas las fechas asociadas a un evento (puede haber varias si el evento se repite) la primera de todas. El objetivo es llevarla al objeto "tratamentos", a las filas asociadas al paciente correspondiente.
El código con bucles debería funcionar tal cual está aquí (creo), pero al ser millones de datos R se atasca, y necesitaría vectorizarlo.
Perdón si me extendí demasiado.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. Por favor, el código va siempre como texto, así como nadie te va a responder con imágenes pa ponerte a transcribir. La opción editar está bajo la pregunta y las etiquetas

Comment: Gracias Alfabravo!

Comment: Vendría muy bien que expliques que es lo que hace el código o al menos que es lo que buscas

Comment: Graciñas @PatricioMoracho. En un principio no lo hice por temor a ser demasiado lioso. Espero que no resulte muy tedioso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si tienes datos similares a este ejemplo:

```
tratamentos <- data.frame(ID=c('AA', 'BB'))
eventos <- data.frame(ID=c('BB', 'AA', 'BB'), 
                      evento = rep('insuf.cardiaca', 3),
                      FECHA= c('2021-01-03', '2021-05-17', '2021-09-10'))
```

Entiendo que lo que buscas puede resolverse de manera relativamente sencilla mediante `dplyr`:

```
library(tidyverse)

tratamentos %>% 
  left_join(eventos, by = "ID") %>% 
  filter(evento == "insuf.cardiaca" ) %>% 
  arrange(ID, FECHA) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(EVENTO_ID = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols=ID, names_from=EVENTO_ID, values_from=FECHA, names_prefix='evento')

# A tibble: 2 × 3
# Groups:   ID [2]
  ID    evento1    evento2   
  <chr> <chr>      <chr>     
1 AA    2021-05-17 NA        
2 BB    2021-01-03 2021-09-10
```

El resultado final será un `data.frame` con `n` columnas con la fecha de cada evento asociado a cada paciente. Las clausulas `dplyr` son bastante explicativas:

1. Unimos mediante un `left_join` las dos tablas, relacionadas por el `ID` del paciente, terminaremos con un conjunto de filas para cada paciente y cada evento.
2. Filtramos el evento deseado mediante `filter()`
3. Ordenamos por paciente y fecha para terminar generando un `ID` para cada evento
4. Finalmente llevamos la estructura vertical a una horizontal, convirtiendo cada `FECHA` en una nueva columna para cada paciente.

Comment: Muchas gracias @PatricioMoracho. No conocía "dplyr" y me has ayudado a resolver el problema con tu aportación.